# Using Ruby on Rails Without the ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I've been considering switching from using PHP to Ruby on Rails for my web projects and the one thing I'm most concerned about is the use of the ActiveRecord for Rails. It seems to me like using the ActiveRecord is very strongly encouraged and writing straight SQL seems frowned upon. After looking at several projects I have yet to see one that actually uses SQL in it.

I'm not sold on the ActiveRecord yet, mostly because it requires learning something that doesn't seem as powerful as straight SQL, e.g. is there an easy way to do a nested query with a group by and having clause with the ActiveRecord or will I have to jump through hoops to do so?

Has anyone ever used Rails without the ActiveRecord? If so, what was your experience doing so?

Comment: Could you provide us with the query you're using as an example?

Comment: I'm not talking about any particular query, but just more complex ones in general.

Comment: The big advantage using the ActiveRecord, or Sequel or Datamapper ORMs is portability. If you use the ORM you can often change the connection DSN or URL and work on a different DBM without changing your code. Writing the SQL directly tempts us to use DBM-specific commands which reduce portability. The ORMS give us the flexibility to decide when to use SQL directly or rely on their ability to generate good code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use ActiveRecord you don't have to and can define pure sql in your models if you so wish. find_by_sql('select whatever')

Comment: Thanks for the accept but Ryan's answer is far more complete than mine and very good advice.

Answer (score 50):

Three words: ***Here be dragons***.

By going off the path of doing things "The Rails Way", then you will encounter foes of unimaginable power and cunning. At first, you will think "OH HO HO I am doing it *my* way, aren't I awesome?". Then you'll grow tired. *Exhausted* even. Forlornly, during your struggles, you'll look at all the [cool gem](http://github.com/radar/by_star)s that are using Active Record and wonder why you chose to venture down a path so fraught with doom and gloom it would make Chuck Norris shit his pants.

Please, do not stray from Active Record. It is only here to help you, not hinder you. If you wish to write your own queries then there is a `find_by_sql` method, or an even lower `Model.connection.execute` method.  However, these should only be used, much like nuclear weaponry, in times of exceptionally dire needs.

If you don't want to use Active Record at all, then I would encourage you to look at either [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org) or [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/).

DataMapper provides much of the same functionality as Active Record and some have been known to prefer the syntax. As a bit of trivia: it was one of the first gems to be compatible with Rails 3.

Mongoid on the other hand is for MongoDB databases, which some other people also fancy.

I beg again: do not stray from the beaten path, lest you want a beating yourself.

Comment: Seeing how I see Ryan Bigg's name every day (from helping people) at 3am from Rails-Core mailings, I suggest you head his words. :)

Comment: And yet, what if you are trying to work with an existing legacy database—shared by many older applications—whose structure is decidedly not amenable to ActiveRecord?

Comment: @GregoryHigley Then you are doomed.

Comment: "Sequel has restored my faith in Ruby. It's really amazing. The O/RM I've been hoping for for years." -- Sam Smoot, creator of DataMapper

Answer (score 4):

You could use DataMapper. After writing Rails apps and tools for over a year I would -***strongly***- recommend using ActiveRecord. Even if you only ever use Model.find_by_sql("error prone hand written sql using fields that may change over time") instead of Model.find_by_last_name("Smith")

Many smart people have spent many hours working on ActiveRecord and ARL. I beg that you leverage their work.

Answer (score 3):

There must be a good reason for other people to use ORMs in their Rails apps. :)

Especially with Rails 3, ORMs are pluggable - you can easily use DataMapper, or Sequel instead of ActiveRecord.

In any case, models are important (and very powerful) part of any MVC framework. Lot of business logic is placed within models - "fat models" is kind of recommended way of development.

Another good point about existing ORMs is that they actually allow (but not encourage) you to [write](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-find_by_sql) [SQL](http://datamapper.org/docs/find#talking_directly_to_your_datastore) [by hand](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Database.html#M000540) - you could freely write all your queries by hand if you like. But even then, I'd recommend that you leave your queries parametrized and let the library interpolate your parameters (you do that in PHP as well, don't you)?

Comment: Yes, I do parametrize queries in PHP...but most PHP frameworks I've used give me flexibility to write queries using ActiveRecord or straight SQL. I'm more worried about the ActiveRecord not being able to do some of the more advanced things I want and then being stuck with using that particular paradigm.